# How to append array as element to another array in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, append

How do I append `(1 2)` to `(1 1)` to make it `((1 1) (1 2))`?

Comment: bash doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. Step back and tell us the actual problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

As [explained by @njzk2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945183/how-to-append-array-as-element-to-another-array-in-bash#comment121846588_68945183) this is just not possible - Bash does not have a data structure capable of storing arrays of arrays. If you need them you will be *much* better off using a different language. Depending on what you're trying to do Python, Ruby, Java, R, SQL, or others might be appropriate.